# Excel: small horizontal window for showing expression is gone

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm using both Excel 2007 and 2010 in two computers.

[image: The expression window is hidden in Excel 2007]

It's Excel 2007. I remember there used to be a horizontal window that shows the expression of the selected cell. But, as shown in the figure, it's gone now. I can't find any option to show it again. Do you have any idea?

[image: The expression window is shown in Excel 2010]

As you can see the above Excel 2010 image, there is the expression window that I want to see also in Excel 2007.

Answer (score 2):

The horizontal window you are looking for is the **Formula Bar**.

It can be displayed / hidden by choosing the **View** menu on the ribbon and selecting **Formula Bar** (see highlighted area below).

(I can't translate the language from your original screenshot, but I imagine you can find it.)